Does a Rejected Asylum Application in the UK Impact Future Travel and Visa-Free Entry?
I have a hypothetical question about the implications of a rejected asylum application in the UK. If someone applies for asylum in the UK, and their application is ultimately rejected at all stages (by the Home Office and on appeal in court), would this have any impact on their ability to travel in the future?
For instance, if they hold a passport that allows visa-free travel to certain countries, would those countries still admit them after their asylum claim has been denied in the UK? Could the rejected application history create any complications when traveling or entering visa-free countries and ones that need a visa? Will they find problems when applying for residency permits or citizenship by investment programs in other countries.
Additionally, if the person cannot return to their country of citizenship for personal safety reasons, would it still be feasible for them to rely on visa-free travel options, or might they face issues at the border?
I’m curious about how this scenario might play out and whether such a history could create obstacles in practice.

I’m voting to close this question because it is a cross post from travel@SE
